# upload image using alamofire shows this issue (reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)

Tags: swift4, alamofire

i'm trying to upload image to the server my code

```
@IBAction func startUploadClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // get image form uiimageview 
    let image = theImage.image

    // and here is the api example provided by my backend developer 

   //{
   //"Id":11,
   //"FileName":"Hydrangeas.jpg",
   //"ImageData":"base64string"
   //}

    let imageData = convertImageToBase64(image: image!)
    let imageNewData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.7)
    let Id = "\(12)"
    let FileName = "image.jpg"




    let headers = [
        "SecurityToken": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "SecurityToken")!,
        "api_key": "Ml3BHS17tJ89Y3Tf4QC3",
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
    ]


    let parameters = [
        "Id":"\(12)",
        "FileName":"image.jpg",
        "ImageData":"\(imageData)"
        ]


    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!), withName: key)
            }

    },
        to: "https://serverName/AddPhoto", headers: headers,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    debugPrint(response)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):

                print(encodingError)
            }
    }
    )
}
```

this is what shows in command after run the code

> [Request]: POST https://serverName/AddPhoto
>   [Response]:  { URL: https://serverName/AddPhoto } { Status Code: 413, Headers {
>       "Content-Length" =     (
>           0
>       );
>       Date =     (
>           "Mon, 22 Oct 2018 20:52:43 GMT"
>       );
>       Server =     (
>           "Microsoft-IIS/8.5"
>       );
>       "X-Powered-By" =     (
>           "ASP.NET"
>       );
>   } }
>   [Data]: 0 bytes
>   [Result]: FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)
>   [Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 561934363.529, "Initial Response Time": 561934363.836, "Request Completed Time": 561934364.234, "Serialization Completed Time": 561934364.241, "Latency": 0.307 secs, "Request Duration": 0.705 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.006 secs, "Total Duration": 0.711 secs }

Comment: HTTP status code 413 means file size is too big. Check the server setting.

Comment: ok but what about serialization brother ? its gonna disappear if i trying to upload smaller image ?

Comment: in the same time i'm using UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.7) as you see to decrease the size is that incorrect ?

Comment: You are using imageData not imageNewData.

Comment: yes i'm because the backend developer ask me to use base64

Comment: And the serialization issue must be from `responseJSON`. You have to test with `responseData`.

Answer (score 0):

for whom ganna search for that in future 
i solved it by make normal Alamofire request instead of using Alamofire.upload 
because i already convert the image to string here my new code

```
@IBAction func startUploadClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let image = theImage.image
    let imageData = convertImageToBase64(image: image!)


    let headers = [
        "SecurityToken": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "SecurityToken")!,
        "api_key": "Ml3BHS17tJ89Y3Tf4QC",
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
    ]


    let parameters = [
        "Id":"\(balaghID)",
        "FileName":"image.jpg",
        "ImageData":"\(imageData)"
        ]

    Alamofire.request("https://serverName/addPhoto", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: Constant.Header).responseJSON { response in



        if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {

            if let ActionResult = JSON["ActionResult"] as? [String:Any]{

                if let Errcode = ActionResult["Errcode"] as? NSNumber {

                    if Errcode != NSNumber(value: 0) {

                        Helper.showAlert("bad operation", message: "error \(ActionResult["ErrDescription"]!)", VC: self)

                    } else {

                        Helper.showAlert("Great you make it", message: "
```

(ActionResult["ErrDescription"]!)", VC: self)

```
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```